# angularjs data transformation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field that displays some information:

```
<input type="text" id="1" data-transformer="" data-ng-model="number"/>
```

What I need is to change displayed information according to some variable for example:

"number" model is equal to value of 10. And I also have dynamic variable "x" which ranges 0-24. The condition would be: if "x > 23" then instead of original "number" model value 10, I need to display "--".

I thought this would be possible using additional directive "data-transformer="""

```
mbg.directive('transformer', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (s, e, a, m) {
            m.$formatters.unshift(function (model) {
                s.tmp = model;
                return (s.x > 23 ? '--' : model);
            });

            m.$parsers.push(function () {
                return s.tmp;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However this doesn't work as I would like: It works only the first time, the page is loaded and "x" is set, but if "x" value changes nothing happens. I kinda understand why it is like so (it's because  transformer directive acts only when "number" model changes, and not "x").

What I would like to know, how can I achieve result I need?

Comment: watch the variable x and if x>23 change the value of number

Comment: Instead of using directive , You can also do it with the help of function in controller. Or you can use $watch.

Comment: That would work, but I need to have the real value of number back. What I need to is to have one information and display other, something like symfony2 form data transformers work.

Comment: why not using a filter for this?

Comment: I am not sure if I can filter model? It throws: Error: error:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a filter if you can present the number in a non-input element, or you could use a watch and bind your input ng-model to the transformed representation :)

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8784/

HTML

```
Input: <input data-ng-model="number" />
<hr>
<h2>Filter</h2>
<span ng-bind="number | transformer"></span>
<hr>
<h2>Watch</h2>
<div ng-controller="transformerController">
    <input ng-model="transformedNumber" readonly />
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('transformer', function () {
    return function (input, target) {
         return (input > 23 ? '--' : input);
    }
});


myApp.controller('transformerController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('number', function(value) {
        $scope.transformedNumber = (value > 23 ? '--' : value);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I would prefer 1st solution as it is much cleaner, but I do need the input field. The 2nd solution is interesting, but how to I convert the value back to it's original? and also I need to transform the value with a bit different logic "(x > 23 ? '--' : value)" how would I get the value of "x" ?

Comment: The original value is available on $scope.number and the transformed is available on $scope.transformedNumber. You can change the login inside the watch where value is $scope.number.